# Mishneh Torah in english

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, translation, english

To my knowledge, there are two English editions of the Mishneh Torah: the Yale Judaica edition and the Moznaim edition. Furthermore, there exist the Birnbaum (incomplete) and Frankel editions, perhaps others as well of which I am unaware. Which is considered a more exact version?

Criteria

- Edition: which Hebrew edition is the basis
- Faithfulness: which adheres most to the text as given*
- Annotations: text of annotations (other variants, commentary, interpretation)
- Legibility (both visual and textual clarity)

---

*Let us use for example the Artscroll and Soncino editions of Talmud Bavli. The Soncino presents a literal, if somewhat clunky, rendition of the text. On the other hand, Artscroll intersperses its commentary with the translation and obfuscates its faithfulness to follow its own hashkafah.

Comment: There is also a [Birnbaum edition](http://www.amazon.com/Maimonides-Mishneh-Torah-Yad-Hazakah/dp/0884824373) from the 40s (although it is incomplete), and there's also an [edition by Avraham Finkel](https://www.google.com/search?q=avraham+Yaakov+Finkel&oq=avraham+Yaakov+Finkel&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i59l2j69i61j69i59.863j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=avraham+Yaakov+Finkel+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94+%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&safe=off&tbm=bks) which is rather hard to find.

Comment: Thanks, @Bachrach44, I forgot about the Birnbaum edition (presumably due to its incompleteness) and I have never heard of the Finkel edition.

Comment: Closing until you provide some reasonable metric for evaluating "exactness" or whose considerations thereof you care about.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Which is a more exact version?" is opinion-based. "Which is considered a more exact version?" is fact-based: do a survey of people, ask which is a more exact version, and see what answers you get. Not a *good* question IMO, as I doubt any did or will conduct such a survey, but not opinion-based. Do not, however, consider this my unofficial vote to reopen.

Comment: @msh210 Considered by whom? Academics? Rashei Yeshiva? Orthodox Jews? All people?

Comment: @DoubleAA, any of those would make a good answer to that question, I guess. Conduct multiple surveys. `:-)`

Comment: Moznaim is excellent,uses diff texts depending on circumstance,also the notes are great

Comment: Here is a list of English translations, not sure if any of them are based on the corrected texts published in the past 20 or 30 years though:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah#English_translations

Comment: By the way, here's a suggestion - first find out if any of the English translations are based on the newer corrected manuscripts - anything published prior to the 1980's is probably going to be based on the old incorrect editions and is not going to be what you're looking for.

Comment: So annotations are the opposite of faithfulness? Artscroll clearly shows what's the translation and what's the commentary

Comment: No, @ShmuelBrin, the content of the annotations. I find that the Artscroll editions often obfuscate or ignore elements of the relevant material. See http://elucidation-not-translation.blogspot.com/, by the author of On The Mainline.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Most of the issues there on Shas were about their omissions, not additions.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, yes, I know. They also add, at least if I recall learning the mishnayot on the first amud of Berachot out of one correctly.